# How to resize a image according the button, so that it fits in button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add image at the left of the button but it is covering whole of button.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Sign in with Email"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>
```

Comment: Can you show `email` drawable xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a layer-list called `email_layer.xml` with width and height and refer your image to the layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/email"
      android:width="50dp"
      android:height="50dp"/>

</layer-list >
```

now use this as your `android:drawableLeft`

so your button should look like

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_layer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Sign in with Email"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When the parent layout is a linear layout (horizontal property), put the image control in front of the button. If it is relative layout, get the button id in the image control, use layout-left

Comment: I want to add the image inside the button.